# Python-comparing mutliple files from different folders and generating diff files

Tags: python

i want to automate below scenario in python

Actual-

- cc0023-base.txt
- cc9038.final.txt

Expected:

- base.txt
- final.txt

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyLFv.png)"Actual" and "Expected" are two different folders under same directory.i want to compare "base" and "final" files of both folders and generate the diff file in another folder.
Diff:
base-diff.txt
final-diff.txt
how do i do it in python. below is the sample code which i have written,but its generating diff files of all possible combinations.I need that base should be compared only with base and final with final of both folders.

```
    expected_files=os.listdir('expected/path')
    actual_files = os.listdir('actual/path')
    diff_files=os.listdir('diff/path')
    cr=['base.txt','final.txt']
    i=0

    for files in expected_files:
        tst=os.path.join('expected/path',files)
        with open(tst,'r')as Expected:

            for actualfile in actual_files:

                 actualpath=os.path.join('actual/path',actualfile)
                 with open(actualpath,'r') as actual:
                    diff=difflib.unified_diff(Expected.readlines(),
                                              actual.readlines(),
                                              fromfile=Expected,
                                              tofile=actual,)

                    diffpath=os.path.join('diff/path',cr[i])
                    diff_file = open(diffpath, 'w')
                    for line in diff:
                         diff_file.write(line)
                    diff_file.close()
                    i=i+1
```

Please help,as i am new to python

Comment: One thing, not necessarily your issue, but `fromfile` and `tofile` look like they should be strings and you are sending file objects. (from help(difflib.unifiedlib)
`unified_diff(a, b, fromfile='', tofile='', fromfiledate='', tofiledate='', n=3, lineterm='\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is in this section:

```
i=0
diffpath=os.path.join('diff/path',cr[i])
diff_file = open(diffpath, 'w')
for line in diff:
     diff_file.write(line)
diff_file.close()
i=i+1
```

Since you are always setting `i` to `0` before accessing `cr[i]` it will always be `cr[0]`

move the `i=0` to before the loop starts that you want to initialize the value to `0`.

I think you want something like this:

```
expected_files=os.listdir('expected/path')
actual_files = os.listdir('actual/path')
diff_files=os.listdir('diff/path')
cr=['base.txt','final.txt']
j=1

for files in expected_files:
    tst=os.path.join('expected/path',files)
    with open(tst,'r')as Expected:
        #i=0
        for i, actualfile in enumerate(actual_files):

            actualpath=os.path.join('actual/path',actualfile)
            with open(actualpath,'r') as actual:
                diff=difflib.unified_diff(Expected.readlines(),
                                          actual.readlines(),
                                          fromfile=Expected,
                                          tofile=actual,)

                diffpath=os.path.join('diff/path',cr[i])
                with open(diffpath, 'w') as diff_file:
                    for line in diff:
                        diff_file.write(line)
                #diff_file.close()
                #i=i+1
```

Some explanation, so the `enumerate(actual_files)` will give you an index `i` and the data from the list `actualfile` this way you don't have to do the incrementing yourself. (Also worth noting that this **will** break for more than 2 files in your directory!) Also, you can use `with open() as foo:` syntax for writes as shown.